# Licensing for Ubuntu cloud components

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu-based OpenStack private cloud with 20 - 25 servers.  If I follow the automated install provided with the Ubuntu iso, can I provision ALL of my servers without licensing issues.  I know Landscape is limited to 10 machines but can I do a normal automated install (MaaS) on ALL 25 servers and then just disable Landscape or will I have to follow a non-automated install in order to provision these machines ?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the install resources on the ISO and not the [OpenStack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/autopilot), then there are no licensing restrictions at all and you can provision and install on as many servers as you want.

If you want to use the Autopilot and/or manage those machines with [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com) post-install, you'll need to purchase additional seats to cover your needs. Hope that helps.